# How to wait until Realm.io Migration finish?

Tags: ios, migration, realm

I do the migration in `Appdelegate` but I also have the logic to show which navigation controller base on UserObject from Realm.

```
[RLMRealm setSchemaVersion:3
            forRealmAtPath:[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath]
        withMigrationBlock:^(RLMMigration *migration, NSUInteger oldSchemaVersion) {

            [migration enumerateObjects:App.className
                                  block:^(RLMObject *oldObject, RLMObject *newObject) {                                 
                                      if (oldSchemaVersion < 3) {
                                          newObject[@"watchedTutorial"] = false;
                                      }
                                  }];
        }];


if([[UserManager sharedInstance] isUserLoggedIn]){

    UINavigationController *navController = [MAIN_STORYBOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookingNavController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    self.navController = navController;

}else{

    UINavigationController *navController = [MAIN_STORYBOARD instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = navController;
    self.navController = navController;

}
```

Application crashes because `[[UserManager sharedInstance] isUserLoggedIn]` is accessed before the migration is finished in background. What should I do to overcome this issue?

Thanks

**Update:**
Here is UserManager Code for reference

```
class UserManager: NSObject{

    // Singleton    
    class var sharedInstance: UserManager {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: UserManager?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = UserManager()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }

    // Vars
    var realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    var currentUser:User?

    // Class Methods
    func getCurrentUser() -> (User){

        let result = User.allObjects();
        if result.count > 0 {
            currentUser = result[0] as? User

        }else{
            let obj = User()
            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.addObject(obj)
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()
            currentUser = obj
        }

        return currentUser!
    }

    func isUserLoggedIn() -> (Bool){
        return AppManager.sharedInstance.isLoggedInAsGuess()
    }
}
```

Exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'App' due to the following errors:
- Property 'watchedTutorial' has been added to latest object model.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010edb2f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ea4abb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   MyApp                            0x000000010b6c7edb _Z24RLMVerifyAndAlignColumnsP15RLMObjectSchemaS0_ + 5707
    3   MyApp                            0x000000010b6c668b RLMRealmSetSchema + 875
    4   MyApp                            0x000000010b6c8144 RLMUpdateRealmToSchemaVersion + 196
    5   MyApp                            0x000000010b71476d +[RLMRealm realmWithPath:key:readOnly:inMemory:dynamic:schema:error:] + 4813
    6   MyApp                            0x000000010b713158 +[RLMRealm realmWithPath:readOnly:error:] + 152
    7   MyApp                            0x000000010b712faf +[RLMRealm defaultRealm] + 111
    8   MyApp                            0x000000010b53ee48 _TFC8MyApp11UserManagercfMS0_FT_S0_ + 72
    9   MyApp                            0x000000010b53d0c2 _TFC8MyApp11UserManagerCfMS0_FT_S0_ + 50
    10  MyApp                            0x000000010b53f0a5 _TFFC8MyApp11UserManagerg14sharedInstanceS0_U_FT_T_ + 21
    11  MyApp                            0x000000010b489087 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 39
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010fc737f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010fc60343 dispatch_once_f + 565
    14  MyApp                            0x000000010b53cf15 _TFC8MyApp11UserManagerg14sharedInstanceS0_ + 229
    15  MyApp                            0x000000010b53d179 _TToFC8MyApp11UserManagerg14sharedInstanceS0_ + 25
    16  MyApp                            0x000000010b5d2e89 -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 1097
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d78e475 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 234
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010d78efbc -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2463
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010d791d2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010d790bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000112a202a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ece853c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecde285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecde045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ecdd486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d790669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010d793420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    28  MyApp                            0x000000010b5d7183 main + 115
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010fca7145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm never automatically spawns new threads to accomplish work, and performing a migration is no exception.

Also, calling `setSchemaVersion:forRealmAtPath:withMigrationBlock:` will *define* a migration, but won't actually perform it until you access the realm for the first time. In your code, I assume that the `isUserLoggedIn` method on the `UserManager` singleton accesses the realm, which would then trigger the migration.

I'd have to see the code involved in creating the `UserManager` singleton and invoking `isLoggedIn` to give you more insight as to why your app is crashing.

Are you sure Realm isn't throwing an exception here? If uncaught, that will crash your app. If this is the case, please share the exception message here.

You can learn more about how migrations work in Realm from our documentation: http://realm.io/docs/cocoa#migrations

Comment: understand now. Updated the question but I've also resolved the issue by removing the `RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];` code before calling UserManager in AppDelegate. 
So the point here is Realm will auto Migrate and act accordingly when it's called for first time, right?
But why removing `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]` solved the issue?

I had following code between Realm Migration and UserManager in Appdelegate

    `NSLog(@"ResourcePath %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]);`
    `NSLog(@"RealmPath %@",[RLMRealm defaultRealmPath]);`

Comment: I'd really recommend against using a singleton pattern here because it will mean that the realm property won't be thread-safe. If you still have problems after making this change, please send us an Xcode project we can use to reproduce your issues.